# I'm facing 100% height issue in bootstrap html

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm not able to set 100% height left side bar. I have tried all possible ways, here I am using bootstrap column. Please help me on this. Thank you

```
<body>
<div class="container-fluid main-template">  
<div class="row">    
<div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 left_side">left_side</div>
<div class="col-sm-9 col-md-10 right_side">right_side</div>
</div>
</div>
<footer class="main-footer">
</body>
```

And I have set height 100% for html, body, main-template, row, left_side and right_side. still it is not working.

```
html, body {
    background-color:#ffffff;
    min-height: 100%;
}

.main-template {
    padding:0px;
    height:100%;
}
.row {
        height:100%;
}
.left_side, .right_side {
    min-height:100%;
    padding-right: 0px !important;
    padding-left: 0px !important;
}
```

footer css:

```
.main-footer {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    padding: 10px 20px 5px;
    width:100%;
    background-color:#33b3e3;
    height:50px;
}
```

Comment: use `!important` so that it will override the bootstrap css

Comment: I have used !important also, still not working

Comment: are you looking for something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/99x50s2s/105/

Answer (score 1):

You should use `position:relative` for `body` and `html` tags

```
html, body {
    background-color:#ffffff;
    height: 100%;
    position:relative;
}
```

example:
https://jsfiddle.net/16r781ys/

Comment: you code is working. But when scroll down, footer is showing in middle. It should be in bottom always. see css for footer above

Comment: there you go; https://jsfiddle.net/16r781ys/2/ I used display:table for .row and display:table-cell for right and left side divs. also removed float:left from them

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this, you need to add `transform` value in `media css`

```css
html, body {
    background-color:#ffffff;
    min-height: 100%;
}

.main-template {
    padding:0px;
    height:100%;
}
.row {
        height:100%;
}
.left_side{
  position: absolute;
  min-height:100%;
  background-color: #ccc;
}
 .right_side{
  background-color: #e5e5e5;
    -ms-transform: translate(19.6%); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: translate(19.6%); /* Safari */
     transform: translate(19.6%);
 }

.left_side, .right_side {
    
    padding-right: 0px !important;
    padding-left: 0px !important;
}

@media (max-width: 991px) and (min-width:768px) {
 .right_side{
    -ms-transform: translate(33.6%); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: translate(33.6%); /* Safari */
     transform: translate(33.6%);
 }
}
 @media (max-width: 768px) and (min-width:320px) {
  .right_side{
    -ms-transform: translate(9.6%); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: translate(9.6%); /* Safari */
     transform: translate(9.6%);
 }
  }
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid main-template">  
  <div class="row">    
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 left_side">left_side</div>
    <div class="col-sm-9 col-md-10 right_side">right_side</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I hope it will helps you.

Answer (score 0):

This has been solved already [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/skelly/zrbgw/) Check it out..

HTML

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="span5 fill">
        Hello World
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
  @import url('http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/css/bootstrap.css');

html,body{height:100%;}

.container {
    height:100%;
}

.fill{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    min-height:100%;
    background-color:#990000;
    padding:10px;
    color:#efefef;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Heres a very simple way to build a sidebar.

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
}
.sidebar-fixed {
  padding: 5px 18px;
  position: fixed;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: #f5f5f5;
}
.main-content {
  padding-top: 5px;
  margin-left: 200px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="sidebar-fixed">
  <div class="alert alert-info">Sidebar</div>
</div>
<div class="main-content">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="alert alert-info">Content</div>
    <p>Yaygın inancın tersine, Lorem Ipsum rastgele sözcüklerden oluşmaz. Kökleri M.Ö. 45 tarihinden bu yana klasik Latin edebiyatına kadar uzanan 2000 yıllık bir geçmişi vardır. Virginia'daki Hampden-Sydney College'dan Latince profesörü Richard McClintock,
      bir Lorem Ipsum pasajında geçen ve anlaşılması en güç sözcüklerden biri olan 'consectetur' sözcüğünün klasik edebiyattaki örneklerini incelediğinde kesin bir kaynağa ulaşmıştır. Lorm Ipsum, Çiçero tarafından M.Ö. 45 tarihinde kaleme alınan "de Finibus
      Bonorum et Malorum" (İyi ve Kötünün Uç Sınırları) eserinin 1.10.32 ve 1.10.33 sayılı bölümlerinden gelmektedir. Bu kitap, ahlak kuramı üzerine bir tezdir ve Rönesans döneminde çok popüler olmuştur. Lorem Ipsum pasajının ilk satırı olan "Lorem ipsum
      dolor sit amet" 1.10.32 sayılı bölümdeki bir satırdan gelmektedir.</p>
    <p>Yaygın inancın tersine, Lorem Ipsum rastgele sözcüklerden oluşmaz. Kökleri M.Ö. 45 tarihinden bu yana klasik Latin edebiyatına kadar uzanan 2000 yıllık bir geçmişi vardır. Virginia'daki Hampden-Sydney College'dan Latince profesörü Richard McClintock,
      bir Lorem Ipsum pasajında geçen ve anlaşılması en güç sözcüklerden biri olan 'consectetur' sözcüğünün klasik edebiyattaki örneklerini incelediğinde kesin bir kaynağa ulaşmıştır. Lorm Ipsum, Çiçero tarafından M.Ö. 45 tarihinde kaleme alınan "de Finibus
      Bonorum et Malorum" (İyi ve Kötünün Uç Sınırları) eserinin 1.10.32 ve 1.10.33 sayılı bölümlerinden gelmektedir. Bu kitap, ahlak kuramı üzerine bir tezdir ve Rönesans döneminde çok popüler olmuştur. Lorem Ipsum pasajının ilk satırı olan "Lorem ipsum
      dolor sit amet" 1.10.32 sayılı bölümdeki bir satırdan gelmektedir.</p>
    <p>Yaygın inancın tersine, Lorem Ipsum rastgele sözcüklerden oluşmaz. Kökleri M.Ö. 45 tarihinden bu yana klasik Latin edebiyatına kadar uzanan 2000 yıllık bir geçmişi vardır. Virginia'daki Hampden-Sydney College'dan Latince profesörü Richard McClintock,
      bir Lorem Ipsum pasajında geçen ve anlaşılması en güç sözcüklerden biri olan 'consectetur' sözcüğünün klasik edebiyattaki örneklerini incelediğinde kesin bir kaynağa ulaşmıştır. Lorm Ipsum, Çiçero tarafından M.Ö. 45 tarihinde kaleme alınan "de Finibus
      Bonorum et Malorum" (İyi ve Kötünün Uç Sınırları) eserinin 1.10.32 ve 1.10.33 sayılı bölümlerinden gelmektedir. Bu kitap, ahlak kuramı üzerine bir tezdir ve Rönesans döneminde çok popüler olmuştur. Lorem Ipsum pasajının ilk satırı olan "Lorem ipsum
      dolor sit amet" 1.10.32 sayılı bölümdeki bir satırdan gelmektedir.</p>
    <p>Yaygın inancın tersine, Lorem Ipsum rastgele sözcüklerden oluşmaz. Kökleri M.Ö. 45 tarihinden bu yana klasik Latin edebiyatına kadar uzanan 2000 yıllık bir geçmişi vardır. Virginia'daki Hampden-Sydney College'dan Latince profesörü Richard McClintock,
      bir Lorem Ipsum pasajında geçen ve anlaşılması en güç sözcüklerden biri olan 'consectetur' sözcüğünün klasik edebiyattaki örneklerini incelediğinde kesin bir kaynağa ulaşmıştır. Lorm Ipsum, Çiçero tarafından M.Ö. 45 tarihinde kaleme alınan "de Finibus
      Bonorum et Malorum" (İyi ve Kötünün Uç Sınırları) eserinin 1.10.32 ve 1.10.33 sayılı bölümlerinden gelmektedir. Bu kitap, ahlak kuramı üzerine bir tezdir ve Rönesans döneminde çok popüler olmuştur. Lorem Ipsum pasajının ilk satırı olan "Lorem ipsum
      dolor sit amet" 1.10.32 sayılı bölümdeki bir satırdan gelmektedir.</p>
    <p>Yaygın inancın tersine, Lorem Ipsum rastgele sözcüklerden oluşmaz. Kökleri M.Ö. 45 tarihinden bu yana klasik Latin edebiyatına kadar uzanan 2000 yıllık bir geçmişi vardır. Virginia'daki Hampden-Sydney College'dan Latince profesörü Richard McClintock,
      bir Lorem Ipsum pasajında geçen ve anlaşılması en güç sözcüklerden biri olan 'consectetur' sözcüğünün klasik edebiyattaki örneklerini incelediğinde kesin bir kaynağa ulaşmıştır. Lorm Ipsum, Çiçero tarafından M.Ö. 45 tarihinde kaleme alınan "de Finibus
      Bonorum et Malorum" (İyi ve Kötünün Uç Sınırları) eserinin 1.10.32 ve 1.10.33 sayılı bölümlerinden gelmektedir. Bu kitap, ahlak kuramı üzerine bir tezdir ve Rönesans döneminde çok popüler olmuştur. Lorem Ipsum pasajının ilk satırı olan "Lorem ipsum
      dolor sit amet" 1.10.32 sayılı bölümdeki bir satırdan gelmektedir.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```